# how to get a average of days with two different tables

Tags: asp.net

There are two tables 1)HR_OrderRequest (column to be considered is HRdate) other columns are HRUID,UID
                     2)HR_Supplydetails(colmn to be considered is HRUID) other columns are createddttm,UID
by considering the date from HR_Supplydetails we should find the average days taken for that particular UID time taken to release of HRdate .I have a problem getting a average of days

Please do the need .

Answer (score 0):

so the steps would be first getting the number of days for a order so you have like these tables:

```
order (id, date) # this date is the date the order was placed
supply (id, date) # this date is the date the order was filled
```

these might not be right but i think they are close

```
select avg(days)
from (select (supply.date-order.date) as days
     from order join supply on order.id=supply.id)
```

but the sub query isn't needed as it can be written as:

```
select avg(supply.date-order.date)
from order join supply on order.id=supply.id;
```

now to map this to your tables:

```
HR_OrderRequest (HRUID, UID, HRdate)
HR_Supplydetails (HRUID, UID, createddttm)

select avg(HR_OrderRequest.HRdate-HR_Supplydetails.createddttm)
from HR_OrderRequest join HR_Supplydetails on HR_OrderRequest.HRUID=HR_Supplydetails.HRUID
where UID=?
```

clearly if you have date functions use them

Answer (score 0):

You can do a datediff:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, createddttm,HRdate))
```

And then do your join on the two tables.